# Partitioning a system for a new SSD?

Tags: ssd, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSD with multiple partitions - disk life implications](https://superuser.com/questions/86753/ssd-with-multiple-partitions-disk-life-implications)

Ok I finally decided to make the jump to SSD. Seen a deal on a OCZ Vertex 
120GB but after some research i decided to go with the Intel 160GB G2 series for 
just slightly over $100. Also i seen some issues with the vertex drives. I just 
have more faith in the verfiication process of Intel over OCZ/Indilinx.


Anways, my current system consist of the following:
1) Boot Drive - Velociraptor 300GB
2) Data Drive - 750GB 7200 RPM WD

I'll probably keep both those drives in my system and use the SSD as the boot 
drive. The main question i have is HOW careful do i need to be in partitioning 
everything so nothing that writes frequently is on the SSD so as to resit wear / 
slowdowns

For example you could try partition everything that does a lot of writing to the 
velociraptor:
1) Page File
2) Temp Files
3) Hybernate File - don't know if you can change the location but i'll check 
into it if i need to
4) Browser Cache
5) ect......

Depending on what the Write/Read ratio is you might be missing a lot of benefit 
of what the SSD gives you. For example you might be missing the benefit of 
having your system QUICKLY come out of hybernate if you move the hybernate file.

Also, i'm mostly doing this for Visual Studio .Net (programming) improvements. 
Visual Studio projects are "generally" not that that huge but visual studio does 
lots and lots of small writes/reads when doing stuff like reflection,compiling 
ect. I'd like to put these projects on the SSD of course because of speed 
improvements but i don't want to cause performance degradation on my SSD because 
of it. 

I know the intel drive (along with the vertex drive) has TRIM which reduces this 
but i'm sure TRIM is not perfect and you will still see some performance 
degredation over time.TRIM just probably reduces it. Oh, and by the way, i am 
using Windows 7 x64.

Of course there is a lot more examples:
1) Lightroom and its database that its constantly updating
2) Photoshop with its scratch space.
3) SQL Server
4) I'm sure the list could go on and on but i'm sure you get the point.

So when partitioning your drive how anal do you have to be with stuff that does 
writing to the disk. Some of the slowest apps do a lot of writing and probably 
would be helped greatly by a SSD. 

I was even considering (maybe still slightly) of putting this thing in my labtop 
and if i did that i wouldn't have a choice. I would have one drive so everything 
would have to go on the SSD.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hibernate, not hybernate. You can get nicely formatted lists with "1." instead of "1)".  Calling this "partitioning" is confusing, because most people use "partition" to mean how a disk is split up, aka "Volumes" in Windows.

Comment: Althought your question is more detailed it asks exactly the same questions as the duplicate. I would suggest you look at all the questions asked SSD, because almost every question on SSD has already been asked and answered. Your use case does not make your question unique.

Comment: Umm i'm not trying to start a war here but.. Did you happen to read this question? or just read a few words? I understood your closing of my first post and didn't complain but this post should have not be closed. It is in NO way similar to my earlier post EXCEPT for the topic SSDs. I also did a search and there also isn't ANY other other post i could find similar to what i wrote. Maybe you should consider whether your close happy behavior is alienating very users your trying to attract. I know i won't be coming back. This is the only of your 3 big sites that i have had problems.Tweeting away.

Comment: oh yes and by the way. The post your referenced is not a replacement for what i wrote.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. http://superuser.com/questions/86753/ssd-with-multiple-partitions-disk-life-implications is about partitions; this question is not about partitioning, it is about which files should be placed on which disks. The original poster misused the word "partition".

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry too much about the wear on the drive over time. Remember that SSDs follow Moore's Law, so by the time your new drive is old, you'll be eager to replace it anyway. The replacement will be cheaper, faster, and have more capacity.

Do max out the RAM in your machine, as RAM will be faster than swapping and caching is good.

Do put the page file on the SSD, as fast paging is good.

You don't really need to put Visual Studio on the SSD, as it doesn't read itself very often (mostly just at launch or the first time you load a project). Even your source code doesn't need to be on the SSD. But the intermediate (obj) and final (exe/dll) outputs should be on SSD. Putting your whole project on the SSD is probably the easiest way to do that.

The hibernate file is only used when hibernating or waking up from hibernate, and it's as big as your RAM, so moving it to a different disk is probably good.

Comment: OK maybe your right about the wear but how about performance degredation with SSDs. Already at the max my MB can handle (8GB). Yes i know the hibernate file is only used when you system hibernates / wakes up but this is how i run my system mostly because i want it to wake up in the middle of the night to be backed up with windows home server and perform other misc task.