# How to format an Intel 320 SSD to take advantages from their wear leveling function?

Tags: ssd

Since that i can't use TRIM, i wanted to setup in my SSD disks a free space (10%) so that the SSD's controller uses that to do the wear leveling.

How can i do that? With fdisk?

Also, i read this online:

[what's the changed situation with partitions on ssd?](https://superuser.com/questions/199380/whats-the-changed-situation-with-partitions-on-ssd#comment202392_199399)

> the capacity of these Intel SSDs is about 15-20% higher than advertised, the excess space being used for wear leveling.

If this was true, i shouldn't worry about setting up this little free partition, but i would like to have a confirmation from you.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to, or can, do. Wear leveling is a firmware function that takes place automatically. The mapping of user-accessible SSD space to internal SSD space is managed by the firmware and you cannot influence it.

The SSD can tolerate so many writes, and there's nothing you can do to increase or decrease that number.

Comment: Are you sure of this? Because if so, i'm going to setup a ZFS raid on 40 SSDs, and most probably i'm not coming back... An empty partition doesn't help, correct? Many thanks David (that's my name too ;)

Comment: I'm sure. An empty partition doesn't help. It won't make the drive tolerate more writes, it won't make the drive tolerate less writes. The drive already does wear-leveling, so it doesn't matter where you write.

Comment: Also, never ever defragment SSDs or other flash memory like USB stick or SD card.  Defragmenting adds thousands of writes.  SSDs and flash memory are designed to be fragmented (for wear leveling), so I guess it doesn't affect their speed.

Comment: This answer is not correct. While it is true that the Intel SSDs will do wear-leveling no matter what, the amount of writes they can handle greatly depends on free space and where you write. This is specially true for server situations or situations without TRIM.

Comment: @MrAlpha: That conflicts with everything I know about how modern SSDs work. Do you have a source for this claim? (What possible difference could it make to the SSD where you write? You only have access to the SSD's logical mapping of sectors, which the wear-leveling is free to change.)

Comment: @David Schwartz: It has to do with Write-Amplification. How much free space and over what area you are writing affects the WA of the drive, which in turn can have a big effect on drive endurance. Here is an old pdf from Intel discussing the matter: http://mralpha.s3.amazonaws.com/Intel-overprovisioning.pdf  There is also more discussion over at Anandtech: http://www.anandtech.com/show/5518/a-look-at-enterprise-performance-of-intel-ssds

Comment: @MrAlpha: If this is still true for modern Intel SSDs (the one discussed in the article is 4 years old), that indicates truly brain dead firmware in the drive.

Comment: @David Schwartz: The modern Intel drive (even though it is still the same controller) is not quite as brain dead as that document makes it sound. It will use all free space available to reduce WA. So you can partiton the entire space available and still achieve the same effect provided that a) you always make sure to leave empty space, and b) you make sure to TRIM the empty space so the controller knows it is empty. But that is the OP's problem: no TRIM.

Comment: @MrAlpha: That's still pretty brain dead. Any sensible wear-leveling algorithm should find blocks that have very low write counts and swap them for blocks that have very high write counts so that large amounts of "almost never changing data" doesn't waste most of the drive's writes. Wear leveling only unallocated blocks is wear leveling with one hand tied behind your back. If Intel really does that, shame on them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: No, the controller does that, that is not the issue here. The problem arises when it does wear-leveling and garbage collection. Since it can only delete data a block at a time it is in the controllers interest to delay doing anything until all the data on the block is invalid and it doesn't need to move anything when deleting the block. But because of wear-leveling and other functions, sooner or later it must move data. Having lots of free blocks means it can delay doing these things until more of the data is invalid and doesn't need moving, thus lowering write-amplification.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2760/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-mr-alpha)

Comment: The link is death :(